# How to pass a Javascript object to a PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php

```
  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
//$.post("test.php", componentForm);
  }
```

I want to send the componentform object data to the php file! What all I need to do? Please let me know how to do so? I watched a few tutorials but I did not get the result that I need!

Comment: you can send data to php from js by using ajax

Comment: Have you included [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) in your project? The `$` is a wrapper of that library generally called when `document` is ready. Something like inside `$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});`

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys! @Vivek I haven't include jquery in my project

Comment: Then it obviously won't work @Sumit. `$.post` is short for a `POST` Ajax request in Jquery. It's documented here - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. Have a look at Jquery, include it in your project and you should be good to go :)

Comment: where should I mention <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: This is my code <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>

Comment: Then the CSS part and then I have created some fields so that I can catch the location fields using google api

Comment: What I want to do is use the code of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox and store the address data on my database using php

Comment: But I am not getting how to send the address data stored in a javascript variable to php fiile

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };
  

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
//$.post("test.php", componentForm);
  }

function sendData(){
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"/config.php",
  data:'data='+JSON.stringify(componentForm),
  success: function(data){
   //handle response here
   alert(data);
  },
  error: function(){
   alert('AJAX ERROR');
  }
 });
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    sendData();
});
</script>
```